# textpad to excel colunns using jupyter - array based on text condition

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I have a lines in text file and want to convert to excel sheet. Contents in the text file is different and I want them to put it in a array and push it in a excel columns.
Below formula is not giving desired output. Say like below sample sentence, I want to split the sentence in to four columns file to excel sheet using array function.

It searches lines, if the line starts with alphanumeric all upper case, it will be placed in code_id, then the sollowing sentence in code_desc.

Then searches next line, if it starts with "and" lower case word, then the next word check if it is alphanumeric all upper case word. if so, then in code_id_2 column, and the following sentence in code_desc_2.

text lines examples:
03YT0Z1       Transplantation of vehicle
05RF0JE       Replacement of Right gear
and 02RE0JD  Replacement of Left gear

EXPECTED excel output:
column 1             column 2                 column 3                       column 4
03YT0Z1       Transplantation of vehicle
05RF0JE       Replacement of Right gear         02RE0JD     Replacement of Left gear

Please check if the below formula is working fine:

```
`import re
import pandas as pd

# read in the text file
with open('11.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

# initialize the arrays to store the data
code_id = []
code_desc = []
code_id_2 = []
code_desc_2 = []

# split the text into lines
lines = text.split('\n')

# iterate over the lines and extract the data
for i in range(len(lines)):
    # check if the line starts with an alphanumeric upper case word except VRG|DDC,
    if re.match(r'^(?!VRG|DDC)[A-Z0-9]+\b', lines[i]):
        words = lines[i].split(maxsplit=1)
        if words[0].isalnum() and words[0].isupper():
            code_id.append(words[0])
            code_desc.append(words[1])
            # check if the next line starts with "and" and has an alphanumeric upper case word
            if i < len(lines) - 1 and re.match(r"^\s*and [A-Z0-9]+\b", lines[i+1]):
                subcode = lines[i+1].split(maxsplit=1)
                if subcode[0].isalnum() and subcode[0].isupper():
                    code_id_2.append(subcode[0])
                    code_desc_2.append(subcode[1])
            else:
                code_id_2.append('')
                code_desc_2.append('')
                
# create a DataFrame from the arrays
df = pd.DataFrame({'code_id': code_id, 'code_desc': code_desc, 'code_id_2': code_id_2, 'code_desc_2': code_desc_2})

# write the DataFrame to an Excel file
df.to_excel('1.xlsx', index=False)`
```

Comment: You gave a poor description of your *data/problem* and your expected output does not match your code. What if a line starts with `"VRG"` or `"DDC"` ? What if there is two consecutive lines that start with `"and"` ?

Comment: If line starts with VRG or DDC, then it will be omitted. There is no consecutive "and" lines in the text document.

Comment: Thanks, that's much clearer for me now, I posted an answer below ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the options using [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) [*reshaping*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html) :

```
df = (pd.read_csv("11.txt", header=None)
        [0].str.extract(r"^(and)?\s*(?!VRG|DDC)([A-Z0-9]+\b)\s(.*)").dropna(how="all")
          .assign(grp= lambda x: x.pop(0).isnull().cumsum(),
                  cols= lambda x: x.groupby("grp").cumcount())
          .pivot(index="grp", columns="cols").swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
          .droplevel(0, axis=1).set_axis(["code_id", "code_desc", "code_id_2", "code_desc_2"], axis=1)
          .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Output :
​

```
print(df)

   code_id                         code_desc code_id_2                code_desc_2
0  03YT0Z1        Transplantation of vehicle       NaN                        NaN
1  05RF0JE         Replacement of Right gear   02RE0JD   Replacement of Left gear
```